# Lowering elements in subscript to match elements with tilde

Tags: subscripts, tilde

Consider:

```
\[
x_{a}^{+}\qquad x_{\tilde{a}}^{+}
\]
```

[image]

Is there a simple way to make the first "a" the same height as the second one? The problem doesn't occur when the superscripts are removed.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please add an screenshot of your result to your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `\vphantom{\tilde{a}}` in the first subscript to indicate that the height should be at least the height of a `\tilde{a}`. Then the subsripts have the same height ad are therefore positioned in the same way:

```
\[
x_{a\vphantom{\tilde{a}}}^{+}\qquad x_{\tilde{a}}^{+}
\]
```

Comment: Yes, this seems perfect!